# Python specific item from last line

Tags: python, ubuntu, time

I've got solution for many probles I had last few days, but need one more solution.

I'm going to use Python script to read from TXT file, separate items, add time, and save as another TXT file.

Problem is that Python keep reading first line and using only this first line from TXT file.

My txt file with data looks like:

```
T:  55% 24.50   12% 90% N
T:  55% 25.50   12% 90% N
T:  55% 26.50   12% 90% N
T:  55% 27.50   12% 90% N
```

and my new txt file looks like:

```
2013-05-10 21:42:13 24.50
2013-05-10 21:42:14 24.50
```

while it should looks like:

```
2013-05-10 21:42:13 24.50
2013-05-10 21:42:14 25.50
```

Can you help me edit my script to set Python Script read only last line from txt file, separate items, add time and save them into new txt file?

My script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

buffer = bytes()
f = open("arduino.txt")
while buffer.count('T:') < 2:
    buffer += f.read(30)
f.close();
# Now we have at least one complete datum. Isolate it.
start = buffer.index('T:')
end = buffer.index('T:', start+1)
items = buffer[start:end].strip().split()

print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), items[2]
```

Best regards.

Comment: But you are only reading in chunks of 30 bytes from the start of the file every time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the last line like this:

```
fh = open("arduino.txt")
for line in fh:
    pass
last = line
```

Now,

```
#You might want to split based on specific delimiters, but I am using the default
split_line = last.split() #T:  55% 27.50   12% 90% N
```

Now, open another file, and save the contents

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

f = open("arduino.txt")
while line in f:
    pass
f.close();
#line is the last line now

items = line.strip().split()

print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), items[2]
#Write to the new file here.
```